# Update object in useState works only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update the selected object from my useState called choosenProducts and it works fine but only if it has an object, having more than one doesn't work anymore and it sends me the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'newQuantity' before
> initialization

This is my code:

```
    const onChangeQuantityHandler = (id, e) => { 
      const newQuantity = chosenProducts.map( p => {
        if(p._id === id){
          return {
            ...p, quantity:e, subtotal: e * p.price 
          }
        }
        return newQuantity
      })

      setChosenProducts(newQuantity)
     }
```

My input:

```
<input type="number" value={product.quantity} onChange={ (e)=> onChangeQuantityHandler(product._id, e.target.value)  }/>
```

I don't understand why it only works once with a single object. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `return newQuantity` Did you mean `return p`? Or if this is what you meant to do, what effect do you want it to have?

Comment: Also, your newQuantity variable name is misleading, as it stores an array of products, not the new quantity. You need to include more code (what is in chosenProducts?) and elaborate on what you want to achieve